# O código pula o fgets(), não lendo a palavra

Tags: c, console

O programa não esta lendo meu `fgets()` chegando ali ele pula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    float altura, peso,pesoidealm,pesoidealf;

    char sexo[10];

    printf("Digite sua altura\n");
    scanf("%f",&altura);

    printf("Digite seu peso\n");
    scanf("%f",&peso);

    printf("Digite seu sexo\n");
    fgets(sexo,9,stdin);

    pesoidealm=(72.7*altura)-58;
    pesoidealf=(62.1*altura)-44.7;

    if(!(strcmp(sexo,"masculino")))
    {
        printf("Peso Ideal:%f\n",pesoidealm);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E precisa digitar o sexo todo? Não pode ser só a inicial como todo mundo0 faz? E precisa ser com `fgets()`?

Comment: É  que esta pedindo no exercício. E como usar gets (pode dar bufferoverflow), então acho que o melhor a usar é fgets().

Comment: E por que não `scanf()` mesmo?

Comment: Creio que seja por que é uma string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo direto, utilize `getchar();` antes de chamar `fgets`.
O código ficaria assim:

```
printf("Digite sua altura\n");
scanf("%f",&altura);
printf("Digite seu peso\n");
scanf("%f",&peso);
printf("Digite seu sexo\n");

getchar();

fgets(sexo,9,stdin);
```

Comment: Caraca, muito obrigado era isso mesmo!!!

Comment: Isso ocorre porque quando você pressiona ENTER após informar o peso, um '\n' é armazenado no input stream. getchar() vai consumir esse caracter e evitar que seja passado imediatamento ao fgets

Answer (score 6):

A forma simples de fazer isto é usar o `scanf()` mesmo, assim de forma mais simples e organizada no código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    float altura, peso;
    char sexo[10];
    printf("Digite sua altura\n");
    scanf("%f", &altura);
    printf("Digite seu peso\n");
    scanf("%f", &peso);
    printf("Digite seu sexo\n");
    scanf("%9s", sexo);
    if (!strcmp(sexo, "masculino")) printf("Peso Ideal:%f\n", (72.7 * altura) - 58);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/m8yggm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dnxagauz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfString.c).

Comment: Dessa maneira deu certo também, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3):

No meu caso, resolvi apenas limpando o buffer:

```
char nomeJogador1[32];

setbuf(stdin, 0);

printf("Nome do 1° jogador: ");
fgets(nomeJogador1, 32, stdin);
```